# Android - Elements of List are getting replaced automatically

Tags: android, arraylist, android-studio

I have an empty list. I fill it with my class's instances in a loop. And right after adding an instance, I retrieve the last element and check its parameters. The values of parameters are fine.

Now, when I have filled all the values and control gets out of the loop, the `date` and `time` (which are instances of `Calendar`) of all the elements of that list are somehow replaced with the very last element's `date` and `time`, whereas the rest of parameters remain the same. I don't know if there is a **logical error** in my code or there is a **bug in Android Studio**.

I am printing out the values to Logcat, before entering the element and after entering that element. The values are same. But when the control reaches `cursor.close()`, all elements in that list are replaced.

```
public List<YearChart> readYearChart() throws Exception {
    List<YearChart> yearChart = null;

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = TheApplication.getDateFormat();
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = TheApplication.getTimeFormat();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MyDatabaseHelper.table_YearChart, super.columnsToRetrieve, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        yearChart = new ArrayList();
        int id;
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        int namazId;
        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        int i=0;
        do
        {
            id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(super.columnsToRetrieve[0]));
            String dateStr = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(super.columnsToRetrieve[1]));
            namazId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(super.columnsToRetrieve[2]));
            String timeStr = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(super.columnsToRetrieve[3]));
            if(!dateStr.isEmpty() && !timeStr.isEmpty())
            {
                date.setTime(dateFormat.parse(dateStr));
                time.setTime(timeFormat.parse(timeStr));
                YearChart yc = new YearChart(id, date, namazId, time);
                Log.v("YearChart_ID  >", String.valueOf(yc.getId()));
                Log.v("YearChart_Date>", TheApplication.getDateFormat().format(yc.getDate().getTime()));
                Log.v("YearChart_NID >", String.valueOf(yc.getNamazId()));
                Log.v("YearChart_Time>", TheApplication.getTimeFormat().format(yc.getTime().getTime()));
                Log.v("*****", "*****");
                yearChart.add(yc);
                YearChart yc1 = yearChart.get(i);
                Log.v("YearChart_ID  >", String.valueOf(yc1.getId()));
                Log.v("YearChart_Date>", TheApplication.getDateFormat().format(yc1.getDate().getTime()));
                Log.v("YearChart_NID >", String.valueOf(yc1.getNamazId()));
                Log.v("YearChart_Time>", TheApplication.getTimeFormat().format(yc1.getTime().getTime()));
                Log.v("*****", "*****");
                i++;
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();

    return yearChart;
}
```

I am using Android Studio (v1.1.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the same reference to date and time - meaning each element in the list holds a reference to those exact objects. When you call date/time methods, you'll be updating those two variables which all your list items point to.

The solution is to move the instantiation of date and time into the do-while loop.